# Testing React Native image Picker Library with Jest

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm new with jest testing, Can someone help me to test this function with jest, here's my code :

```
import { launchCamera,launchImageLibrary } from "react-native-image-picker"
jest.mock('react-native-image-picker',()=>{
    return{
        launchCamera:jest.fn(),
        launchImageLibrary:jest.fn()
    }
})

export const openGallery = (image:string,setImage:Function):Function =>{
    const option = {
        mediaType : 'photo',
        quality : 0.6
    }
    launchImageLibrary(option,(res)=>{
        if(res.didCancel){
            console.log('User Cancel Image Picker')
        }else if(res.errorCode){
            console.log(res.errorCode)
        }else{
            const data= res.assets[0]
            setImage(data.uri)
            console.log(data.uri)
        }
    })
    return image
}
```

where *image* and *setImage* is a *useState*

Thanks a lot for helping me!